# How to find all SCNMaterials in a model, that uses texture files

Tags: ios, macos, scenekit

I am attempting find all **SCNMaterials** with texture files in a model (.scn file) with the following code.

```
 NSArray *identifiers = [sceneSource identifiersOfEntriesWithClass:[SCNMaterial class]];
    for (NSString *identifier in identifiers) {
        // iterate thru' each material to find diffuse.contents with a file.
    }
```

But the identifiers array is empty. BTW, the model loads fine. And there are several named materials.

```
  // materials from a node.
 (lldb) po [node.geometry materials]
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x1c001d490>(
<SCNMaterial: 0x1c43c4920 'ITEM1'
  diffuse=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40cff10 | contents=foo.png>
  ambient=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c42c1f80 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.408964 0.408952 0.408959 1>
  specular=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c42c3d40 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1>
  emission=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40ceb60 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1>
  transparent=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40cb050 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.999974 0.999991 1>
  reflective=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40cb8a0 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1>
  multiply=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40d2440 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.999974 0.999991 1>
  normal=<SCNMaterialProperty: 0x1c40d2360 | contents=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.999974 0.999991 1>
>
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this posting [in Apple forums and the response by @toyos](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27618), it looks like this method works only with dae files and not with scn files.  I can confirm that too.